# How to Pass/Fail a Cucumber Test Step based on a SQL Server Query Result

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber

I am writing Automated Test Cases, using Cucumber/Gherkin syntax.

One particular Scenario involves verifying that a row has been successfully added to a database.

So I want the test to pass/fail based on a SELECT statement which checks if a particular ID has been persisted to the database.

If the ID passed into the SELECT statement does exist, then PASS.

If the ID does not exist in the database, FAIL.

Currently, I am able to display the row data (So the ID is being persisted), but even if I query an invalid ID, the test still passes.

Below is my current code:

```
 @Then("BR API will insert a record into tBookingRequestRejections table in the BR Staging DB tables. The record will contain the error code and error description.")

 public void br_API_will_insert_a_record_into_tBookingRequestRejections_table_in_the_BR_Staging_DB_tables_The_record_will_contain_the_error_code_and_error_description() {

    try {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection m_Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DETAILS);
        Statement m_Statement = m_Connection.createStatement();         
        String query = "select top 10 * from tBookingRequest where request_id = " + idNumber; 

        ResultSet m_ResultSet = m_Statement.executeQuery(query);

        while (m_ResultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("HERE: " + m_ResultSet.getString(1) + ", " + m_ResultSet.getString(2) + ", "
                    + m_ResultSet.getString(3));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
```

How can I make the Cucumber Test pass/fail based on the value returned from this query?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Depends... Is it true that m_ResultSet.getString(1) returns an empty string when nothing has been persisted? Then you can use an assert (from Junit or Hamcrest for instance) to assert your result and fail if necessary.

Comment: First, remove this Exception ex. Add specific exception that might arise.  Second, separate your logic in layers, e.g load elements, asserts, db and etc.

Answer (score -1):

In general when cuking you should verify via the user interface not by looking directly at the database. If your users can't see the record has been added, or perhaps your api doesn't confirm that the record has been added then that behaviour is invisible.

Now this doesn't mean you shouldn't;t test the record is in the database what it suggests is that you can write a much faster unit test  to do this, or that you should improve the interaction so you can test visible results.

Its worth remembering that well written unit tests can be one, two or even three orders of magnitude faster than a Cucumber scenario (depending on what you test).

Comment: Let's not confuse selenium with cucumber. You can easily use cucumber to specify scenarios that run entirely without browsers. So it may or may not be a good idea to write your test differently.

Comment: I am testing micro services, and there is no user interface

Comment: I have spoken to the client, and the XML response schema validation (implying the record has been added) will suffice for now

Comment: if you are testing microservices you have two approaches that are probably better than the one you are trying. The first is to write a unit test. The second is to ensure that the service api has something that confirms the record has been added (when dealing with services the user interface is the service api). Both approaches are preferable to cuking and looking at the database directly. The first is much faster. The second ensures your api is sufficient to confirm your behaviour is implemented.